# Iterar una lista con mat-grid-list y con *ngFor

Tags: angular, iteradores, ngfor

Como puedo hacer para que los elementos que son iterados en un *ngFor sean divididos en 3 columnas?
Actualmente el codigo me muestra los mat-checkbox uno debajo de otra en una sola columna

```
        <mat-checkbox 

          [(ngModel)]="materia.checked"     
          color="primary"
          (change)="materia($event, materia)"
        >
        {{materia.tarjeta.nombre}} ({{materia.tarjeta.tarjetaCodigo}})
      </mat-checkbox>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con mat-grid-list se soluciona la ubicacion de las columnas:

```
     <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1" *ngFor="let materia of materias" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
       <mat-checkbox [disabled]="editMode" [(ngModel)]="materia.checked" color="primary"
         (change)="tarjetaSeleccionada($event, tarjeta)">
         {{materia.tarjeta.nombre}} ({{materia.tarjeta.tarjetaCodigo}})
       </mat-checkbox>
     </mat-grid-tile>
   </mat-grid-list>
```